# What is the probability of two people of the same race randomly sitting next to each other in a room?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Imagine there are four people, two of them are white, and two of them are asian. There are 2 chairs on one side of a room and 2 on the other side. Everyone is randomly assigned a seat. What is the probability that two people of the same race are seated on the same side of the room?

My intuition leads me to believe the probability is 1/3, since it can be thought of in terms of pulling colored balls from a bucket. There are two red balls and two blue balls. The color of the first ball doesn't matter, whichever color is chosen, there will be one left of the same color and two left of opposite color, hence 1/3 chance of choosing a ball of same color. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct